# Changed Id to Class. Jquery stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I changed an ID to Class on html and CSS. And Jquery stopped working. The dots showing the amount of pages and the page selected don't show anymore. it's code from my mobile app

Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/b2y8E/1/

also, there is this js script in the html page:

```
    $.ui.ready(function(){
    carouselSetup();
});        

function carouselSetup(){
    // set size of carousel
    $(".carousel").width($(".carousel").closest(".panel").width());
    $(".carousel").height($(".carousel").closest(".panel").height()-25);

    var options={
       vertical:false, // page up/down
       horizontal:true, // page left/right
       pagingDiv:"carousel_dots", // div to hold the dots for paging
       pagingCssName:"carousel_paging", //classname for the paging dots
       pagingCssNameSelected: "carousel_paging_selected", //classname for the selected page dots
       wrap:true //Creates a continuous carousel
    }
    var carousel = $(".carousel").carousel(options);
```

Comment: Stopped working? That's vague.

Comment: That sounds very suspiciously like a typo somewhere.  If you can remove a bunch of lines and narrow it down to a smaller question, and show us both the before and after and what you changed, either you'll find what you did wrong or we'll be able to help.

Comment: it can be a typo or somewhere in JS , probably you were getting an element by its ID and now when u changed it to class .. that element was undefined ... Can be a reason